# C++ unresolved external symbol (public static int)

Tags: c++

When I try to compile this, I get this linker error:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static int HooksXD::night" (?night@HooksXD@@2HA)
```

The header is this:

```
class HooksXD
{
    public:
        static void XD3();
        static int night;
        static int night2;
};
```

Variables are public not private because I need to access them from other voids witch are not in the same class.

The cpp file:

```
HooksXD lmao;
void HooksXD::XD3()
{
    //this void will be called from other cpp files
    lmao.night = 1;
    lmao.night2 = 1;
};

bool __stdcall CreateMoveClient_Hooked(float frametime, CUserCmd* pCmd)
{
    if (lmao.night = 1)
    {
        //some code
        lmao.night++;
    }
}
```

Comment: cpp file  int HooksXD:: night=0; int HooksXD:: night2=0;  Static member are the class member all object of the class access same variable. So we have to define it seprately.

Comment: As an aside, the line `if (lmao.night = 1)` is almost certainly wrong, that's an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only declared `night` and `night2`, they still need definitions. (because they're `static`)

In your cpp file :

```
int HooksXD::night = 0;
int HooksXD::night2 = 0;
```

And then to access one don't do `lmao.night`, since it's a static you should access it through the type name : `HooksXD::night`.
Make sure you actually need `static` here though.

Comment: How woudl that work if it were a static member data of a class?